# Meteor: why autorun executed twice in onCreated

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

When I declare autorun subscribe in the Template.onCreated function, 
the autorun was fired twice so the publication is triggered twice as well.

```
Route.route 'moneyDepositRequest',
  onRun: ->
    console.log 'onRun'
    Session.set 'condition', where: name: 'example'

Template.moneyDepositRequest.onCreated ->
  console.log 'onCreated'
  @autorun ->
    console.log 'autorun'
    @subscribe 'data', Session.get('condition')

if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.publish 'data', (condition) -> 
    console.log 'data publication'
    Data.find()
```

This code shows this sequence of logs.
**'data publication'**
'onRun'
'onCreated'
'autorun'
'data publication'

I don't understand why **'data publication'** is fired in advance before onCreated executed.

If I declared this autorun action in the onRenderd function, the problem is solved.

How could I understand this?

Answer (score 1):

`Tracker.autorun` always executes the code right away, and then later whenever any reactive variables or functions within it change. So it's running once right away, and then immediately again when the route is triggered. Try this instead:

```
Template.moneyDepositRequest.onCreated ->
  console.log 'onCreated'
  @autorun =>
    console.log 'autorun'

    if !!Session.get('condition')
      @subscribe 'data', Session.get('condition')
```

BTW, as a side note, I start moving away from CoffeeScript. ES6 will <strike>slowly</strike> quickly become the new standard, and CoffeeScript has no roadmap for ES6 transpilation.

Comment: Additionally!! If the CoffeeScript is not included ES6 roadmap, does it mean that We can't use CoffeeScript on the ES6 anymore?? I think if CoffeeScript compiler is updated or use some pollyfill to use it, we can use it right?? HOPEFULLY, I love coffee-

Comment: Keep using CoffeeScript. :) Just know that there might be a couple niche things you won't be able to do that you can do in ES6. As far as `!!Session`, using `!!` just basically turns a truthy element into a proper boolean `true`. You could also just do `if Session.get('condition')` there, that should work fine too.

Comment: In other words: if `x` is set to `"hello"`, then `!!x` will evaluate to `true`. This is because first `!x` is evaluated which evaluates to `false`, then we have `!false` which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for Cool answer~

Comment: I have asked similar but slightly different pattern question here wish you to watch this!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131231/meteor-pattern-template-reuse-and-pub-sub-duplication

Answer (score 0):

I've found my huge mistake finally.
I've set the Session.set 'condition' on the other route using same template, so the Reactive was fired by that new Session condition before the route moved.

And there's one more thing.
If you use IronRouter and use template for several routes, you need to declare template: 'templateName' for every route's map.

For example just suppose that we have three router using same template.

```
Router.route 'first'
Router.route 'second',
  template: 'sharedTemplate'
Router.route 'third',
  template: 'sharedTemplate'
```

In this case, the first route will be fired with onCreated template hooks so the autorun and subscription will be fired again. (for the other templates, the screens are changed for data changes only by reactive subscription.

So if we declare template: 'sharedTemplate' on the first route,
it will work as we expected. (only changed by data when route was changed).

So all the happening was my stupid confusion, but the reactive is complex enough still if we want to use flexibly.